# Debugging Minimum Translation Vector

Tags: c++, collision-detection, physics, separating-axis-theorem

I implemented the minimum translation vector from [codezealot's tutorial on SAT (Separating Axis Theorem)](http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55) but I'm having an issue I can't quite figure out. Here's the example I have:

[image: MTV Example]

As you can see in top and bottom left images regardless of the side the of the green car which red car is penetrating the MTV for the red car still remains as a negative number also here is the same example when the front of the red car is facing the opposite direction the number will always be positive.

When the red car is past the half way through the green car it should switch polarity. I thought I'd compensated for this in my code, but apparently not  either that or it's a bug I can find.

Here is my function for finding and returning the MTV, any help would be much appreciated:

[Code](http://ideone.com/1OGbu)